# How to solve problem of the appearance website IP in Google search results

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, openssl

I published my website on the Internet a year ago, and it has been working normally since then and Google indexed it, but I had an error in my server and Some SSL certificate files were deleted by mistake and I created them again and I solved the problem but since then Google has indexed my IP in the search results with an error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID I don't know what the problem is, although my domain name appears normally in the search results with a valid SSL certificate and at the same time the IP also appears with an invalid certificate. Can anyoneone help me please?

[image]

Comment: If you redirect the IP address to your domain, Google should eventually remove it from their index - see the question marked as a duplicate. (In the future, please try to use screenshots in English so we can better see what's going on)